# django.http.request.RawPostDataException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework

I am making an API and i am gettings ***django.http.request.RawPostDataException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream*** this error
I think You cant access data scnd time:
Here is my code

```py
def get_posts(request):
    print('Called')
    print(request.body)
    data = json.loads(request.body) #Error here
        
    user = data['user']
    print(user)
    
    user_profile = User.objects.all().get(username=user).profile
    
    posts = Post.objects.all().filter(user=user_profile)
    
    if len(posts) == 0:
        return JsonResponse({'last':True,'posts':None})
    
    
    if len(posts) < 4:
        
        data_ = PostSerilizer(data=posts,many=True)
        
        return Response(data=data_)
    
    
    
    else:
        deliverd_count = data['deliverd_count']
        
        posts_to_be_returned = posts[deliverd_count:deliverd_count+4]
        
        to_be_returned = {
            'posts':posts_to_be_returned,
            'last':False,
        }
        
        return JsonResponse(to_be_returned)
```

How can i access data sceond time
Here are the reasons for the error but i dont know how to solve
When i am using api_view decorator -- which is necessary --  and it access data and since django allows you to acces data only one time, I am not able to access it

Comment: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2774

Comment: Can you not assign `request.body` to a variable first? Then read off the variable later again? I haven't tried it tho, just curious.

Comment: Actually no ,cuz it is automatically acceded by the decorator

Comment: When you first assign `copy_body = request.body` it uses the decorator, but when you access `copy_body` it should not access `request.body` again.

Comment: Thanks, but I solved it I acceeded request.data and it is kinda same. Still tnaks for replying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now got the answer. You can say data = request.data ,it is same .